# OS not found when trying to set up a Dell Linux repository

Tags: ubuntu, dell-xps

I am trying to set up a Dell Linux repository, following:

https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/dsu/

There are two steps:

```
To configure the repository, use the following commands:
1. curl -O https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/dsu/bootstrap.cgi
2. bash bootstrap.cgi
```

Step 1 seems to work okay. But when I execute step 2 I get the error:

```
Unable to determine that you are running an OS I know about.
Handled OSs include Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS,
Fedora Core and Novell SuSE Linux Enterprise Server and OpenSUSE
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Two situations: 1. That repository is not for Ubuntu and 2. you may not need any additional repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is mentioned in the error itself. It doesn't host Debian or Ubuntu repos.

The page you linked does mention that

> DSU Ubuntu enablement is only available for 12G and 13G systems

The support for Ubuntu seems to have been dropped.

However according to some answers on [this page](https://www.dell.com/community/Systems-Management-General/Where-is-DSU-Dell-system-updater-Installer-for-Ubuntu-20-04-LTS/td-p/7807196), you might be able to download the DSU from newer models of your product and use them without any problems.

Read the bootstrap script. It doesn't provide for Deb based distros (which also includes Ubuntu). Hence my comment that Ubuntu support might have been discontinued. Also refer to the linked page which mentions the same.